# How to handle authentications in rails with omniauth, devise and facebook

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have implemented facebook authentication in my rails app with devise and omniauth according to this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2 My question is how to handle the authentications objects.

If I understand it right, when I log in with facebook the token is valid for some time and is saved into the authentications table. How the hell is the expiration handled? Even more, If I log out the authentication stays in the table. So when I log in again, it will find the old authentication model. Shouldn't the authentications table be cleared if the user sings out?

Answer (score 0):

The facebook is the one who handles the expiration of authentication in the `facebook`.

What you can control in your rails applicaitons is how devise will expire your authentication. When this happen the user will be prompted to login in facebook again, if it is already logged then he will be redirected authenticated back to your page.

So what you have to control is your settings in devise.

If you want to access the facebook graph, here is a good tutorial to do that:
[Facebook Integration With Omniauth and Devise on Rails 3](http://blog.assimov.net/blog/2010/11/21/facebook-integration-with-omniauth-and-devise-on-rails-3/)

Regards, Felipe Lopes.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, but in that tutorial there is not written how to tell devise/omniauth to handle the token expiration. And I couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: As I told you, you won't have to check when the facebook token expires. You'll set how long you want to user to remain logged to your application, or you may have want the Graph to access users data always. There is no need to check when the facebook token expires. Why do you want it?

Comment: My authentication provider is Facebook, which means my whole authentication relies on Facebook. In the security world if I am provided with an access token and token expires in some time, I should not be allowed to access the resource. As long as my access token comes from facebook I also have to check if its valid. What's the point of the access token than?